# How do I include columns properly in a GROUP BY clause of my Django aggregate query?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, max, aggregate-functions

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have the following model ...

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
```

I want to write a MAX/GROUP BY query subject to certain conditions.  Specifically I want each row to contain

```
MAX(ArticleStat.elapsed_time_in_seconds)
ArticleStat.Article.id
ArticleStat.Article.title
ArticleStat.score
```

in which the columns "ArticleStat.Article.id," "ArticleStat.Article.title," and "ArticleStat.score" are unique per result set row.  So I tried this ...

```
def get_current_articles(self, article):
    qset = ArticleStat.objects.values('article__id', 'article__title', 'score').filter(
        article__article=article).values('elapsed_time_in_seconds').annotate(\
        max_date=Max('elapsed_time_in_seconds'))
    print(qset.query)
    return qset
```

However, the resulting SQL does not include the values I want to use in my GROUP BY clause (notice that neither "article" nor "score" is in the GROUP BY) ...

```
SELECT "myproject_articlestat"."elapsed_time_in_seconds", 
MAX("myproject_articlestat"."elapsed_time_in_seconds") AS "max_date" 
FROM "myproject_articlestat" 
INNER JOIN "myproject_article" ON ("myproject_articlestat"."article_id" = "myproject_article"."id") 
WHERE ("myproject_article"."article_id" = 2) GROUP BY "myproject_articlestat"."elapsed_time_in_seconds"
```

How do I modify my Django query to generate SQL consistent with what I want?

Comment: The query does nto seem to make much sense, you both `GROUP BY` and aggregate (`MAX(..)` on the *same* column).

Comment: I want to MAX on elapsed_time_in_seconds and GROUP BY on 'article__path', 'article__title', and 'score' .  The SQL I included is auto-generated by Django but it doesn't do what I was trying to achieve in the Python code I authored.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, along with desired results?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you need exactly.  In your question you say that you want `GROUP BY Article.id, title, score` but in [Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619487/10746224) you say that you want the results to be unique per `Article.id` (ie `GROUP BY article_id`)

Comment: Let me try and clarify.  There are multiple ArticleStat objects per Article.  I want the MAX(ArticleStat.elapsed_time_in_seconds) per Article, and whatever that ArticleStat object happens to be corresponding to that MAX, I want its score.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the answer by @Oleg will work but it's close..

A Subquery expression can be used to select a single value from another queryset. To accomplish this you sort by the value you wish to target then select the first value.

```
sq = (
    ArticleStat.objects
    .filter(article=OuterRef('pk'))
    .order_by('-elapsed_time_in_seconds')
)
articles = (
    Article.objects
    .annotate(
        max_date=Subquery(sq.values('elapsed_time_in_seconds')[:1]),
        score=Subquery(sq.values('score')[:1]),
    )
    # .values('id', 'path', 'title', 'score', 'max_date')
)
```

Comment: Hi @bdoubleu, I'm getting a "name 'article' is not defined" error on the line ".filter(article=article)".  The "article" is referenced by the ArticleStat object, so maybe we wanted "ArticleStat.objects" two lines above?

Comment: @Dave from what I understand you're looking for I think the filter was unnecessary. The above code will get you all `Article` objects annotated with the `Max('elapsed_time_in_seconds')` and the corresponding `score` from that `ArticleStat` object.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This appears to be working, I'm just running a few more tests.  By any chance, do you know how I would access each row's attributes in a template?  Would it just be {{ row.score }} ?

Comment: If you take out the last line `.values(...)` then that will work. You will have access to each field in the `Article` model as well as the two attributes added through the annotation - `max_date` and `score`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `'elapsed_time_in_seconds'` in your `.values(..)` clause, and add the GROUP BY property in the `.order_by(..)` clause:

```
qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(
    article__article=article
).values(
    'article__path', 'article__title', 'score'
).annotate(
    max_date=Max('elapsed_time_in_seconds')
).order_by('article__path', 'article__title', 'score')
```

This will thus make a `QuerySet` of dictionaries such that each dictionary contains four elements: `'article__path'`, `'article__title'`, `'score'`, and `'max_date'`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I was noticing some odd results so I changed the values and order by sections to be 'article__id', 'article__path', 'article__title', 'score'.  In my results, there were multiple rows that had the same ID, parth, and title.  ID is a unique key so since we did the aggregate function using MAX, shoudln't it just have a single ID with the MAX values for all rows of the same ID?

Comment: @Dave: no, since you include a `score` as well, and multiple `ArticleStat`s can map to the same `Article`, but with a different `score`.

Comment: I see.  How do I write things so that I only return the data (e.g. the score, title, and path) corresponding to the entry with the MAX('elapsed_time_in_seconds')?

Comment: @Dave: there is no straightforward way for that. Normally that means you will need to perform an extra JOIN. See for example: https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it transcends my rudimentary understanding of the Django / aggregate function space.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, there is no one-step way of doing this in Django.

One way of doing it is with 2 queries and to get use of .annotate() to
add the max id of the related object revision for each revision, then
get all those objectrevisions

**Example:**

```
objects = Object.objects.all().annotate(revision_id=Max
('objectrevision__id'))
objectrevisions = ObjectRevision.objects.filter(id__in=
[o.revision_id for o in objects])
```

This is untested and also its a bit slow, so may be you can also try to write custom SQL as mentioned by Wolfram Kriesing in the blog [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130203180037/http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/django-nice-and-critical-article#comment-48425)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite sure to apply what you have here to what I want.  Is Object supposed to be teh equivalent of my Article and ObjectRevision the equivalent of my ArticleStat?

Comment: You should really be using `id__in=objects.values('objectrevision__id')` in order to avoid 2 database hits.  Calling list comprehension on a model forces a query.

Comment: Would you mind phrasing things in terms of the objects I've defined?  I'm struggling to understand if the Object reference you're using is supposed to represent my Article object or ArticleStat object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from all the comments:

Result is to get `Articles` (*id, path, title*) filtered by the `article` argument of `get_current_articles` method with additional data - maximum `elapsed_time_in_seconds` from all the `ArticleStats` of each filtered article and also `score` of its `ArticleStat` with maximum `elapsed_time`.

If so, when the base query can be on `Article` model: `Article.objects.filter(article=article)`.

Which we can annotate with the `Max()` of corresponding `ArticleStats`. This can be done directly on main query `.annotate(max_date=Max(articlestats__elapsed_time_in_seconds))` or with [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) on  `ArticleStat` also filtered the same way as base query on article (we want subquery to run on the same set of article objects as the main query), i.e.

```
max_sq = ArticleStat.objects.filter(
    article__article=OuterRef('article')
).annotate(max_date=Max('elapsed_time_in_seconds'))
```

Now, to add `score` column to the result. `Max()` is aggregate function and it has no row info. In order to get `score` for the maximum `elapsed_time` we can make another subquery and filter by `max elapsed_time` from previous column.

Note: This filter can return multiple `ArticleStats` objects for the same maximum `elapsed_time` and article but we will use only the first one. It is for your data structure to make sure that filter returns only one row or provide additional filtering or ordering such that first result will be the one required.

```
score_sq = ArticleStat.objects.filter(
    article__article=OuterRef('article'),
    elapsed_time_in_seconds=OuterRef('max_date')
)
```

And use our subqueries in the main query

```
qset = Article.objects.filter(
    article=article
).annotate(
    max_date=Max('articlestats__elapsed_time_in_seconds'),
""" or
    max_date=Subquery(
        max_sq.values('max_date')[:1]
    ),
"""
    score=Subquery(
        score_sq.values('score')[:1]
    )
).values(
    'id', 'path', 'title', 'score', 'max_date'
)
```

---

And somewhat *tricky option* without using `Max()` function 
but *emulating* it with `ORDER BY` and fetching the first row.

```
artstat_sq = ArticleStat.objects.filter(
    article__article=OuterRef('article')
).order_by().order_by('-elapsed_time_in_seconds', '-score')
# empty order_by() to clear any base ordering

qset = Article.objects.filter(
    article=article
).annotate(
    max_date=Subquery(
        artstat_sq.values('elapsed_time_in_seconds')[:1]
    ),
    score=Subquery(
        artstat_sq.values('score')[:1]
    )
).values(
    'id', 'path', 'title', 'score', 'max_date'
)
```

Comment: I don't think any of those Subquery expressions will work because you're not calling `.values('article')` to aggregate by article before performing the aggregation - it should be after an empty `.order_by()`. Also `article__article=OuterRef('article')` is incorrect, it should be `article=OuterRef('pk')` because the reference should be directly to `Article` not a model related to it.

Comment: In base Subquery we filter related ArticleStat to get only those of this specific row of Article. Aggregation is done at main query, where we add `.values()` to subquery. Yes, `article__article` is actually `article_id` that is not very clear / mixed from question.